# Wufoo local form processing example

Tags: php, forms, wufoo

I am trying to set up a local Wufoo form. However, I can't get it working.

I am using the XHTML/CSS form code and the Wufoo Rest API V3 (more specifically, I based on the Submit a Form example: http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/examples/). I followed the instructions and filled out the appropriate data in the ApiExamples.php file: API_KEY, SUBDOMAIN, form URL's (checked these by calling them in a browser: OK), email, password and integrationKey. Also, I set the upload-path fo file attachments (although I am not using this).

When I submit he form (using `action="../index.php?functionName=submitForm"`), the result is an empty page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am puzzled. I checked and tried several things. However, I can't get it working. So, I am looking for a working proccesing example file. If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The link to the demo posted seems like a working example. Your question does not give much to go on.  Wufoo is 3rd party and IMHO, you could roll your own with not much more overhead than their setup but say you want Wufoo badly -> I would start by making sure Curl extension is properly installed and configured, I would make sure [php is configured for debugging](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/configure-php-ini-settings-for-a-windows-based-server.3815/), and then, hopefully you would probably have more info to go on.

Good-luck, just post an update here if you need help my friend.